# Issue with printing values in markdown format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Issue i have with the code is when i have two values in each fields for example deviceid: 123,245 and devicemodel: Windows, Linux.

When i execute this script i get the output as attached image. i would like to make different entries such as device id: 123 in 1 and 245 into another. [image: Output]

```
import traceback

try:
    required_fields = ["deviceid","devicemodel"]
    fields = demisto.incidents()[0]['CustomFields']
    filtered_results = []
    test_dict = {}

for key in fields.keys():
    if key in required_fields:
        test_dict[key] = []
        tmp = fields.get(key).lstrip("[").rstrip("]")
        for item in tmp.split(","):
            test_dict[key].append(item)


md = tableToMarkdown("Drill Down", test_dict, headers=required_fields)
data = {
    "Type": entryTypes['note'],
    "ContentsFormat": formats['markdown'],
    "Contents": md,
}
return_results(data)
```

except Exception as ex:
demisto.error(traceback.format_exc())  # print the traceback
return_error(f'Failed to execute AddKeyToList. Error: {str(ex)}')

[image]I am expecting something like this picture but values seprated like index 1 and then index 2. sorry if this is bit unclear but any help is greatly appreciated as i am new to programming.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: this code has mistakes and can't be run. Put minimal working code which we could run. What is `tableToMarkdown`? If you import it from module then you could add this import

Comment: and add example data directly in code.

Comment: there is no error when i run the code, i get the output it's just not what i want

Comment: put minimal working example, example data and expected result with data in result - I don't understand what you expect on second image.

Comment: if you want data in rows then you have to organize them in different way before you send to markdown. And you could use `print()` to see if your code runs in correct way and what you have in variables in different moments. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want to display on second image.

If you want something like this

```
| deviceid | devicemodel |
:----------:-------------:
| 123      | Windows     |
| 245      | Linux       |
```

then first you have to organize data in different way - and you may need `zip()` for this

```
data = {
    'deviceid': '123,245',
    'devicemodel': 'Windows,Linux',
}

# split values

for key in data:
    data[key] = data[key].split(',')

print('\n--- before ---\n')

print(" | ".join(headers))
for row in data.values():
    print(" | ".join(row))

print('\n--- after ---\n')

headers = list(data.keys())
data = list(zip(*data.values()))

print(" | ".join(headers))
for row in data:
    print(" | ".join(row))
```

Result:

```
--- before ---

deviceid | devicemodel
123 | 245
Windows | Linux

--- after ---

deviceid | devicemodel
123 | Windows
245 | Linux
```

---

**EDIT:**

And if you want something like this

```
| Name        | index1  | index2 |
:-------------:---------:--------:
| deviceid    | 123     | 245    |
| devicemodel | Windows | Linux  |
```

then

```
print('\n--- after ---\n')

# create `headers` before `data`
headers = ['Name'] + [f'index{i}' for i in range(1, len(data['deviceid'])+1)]

data = [[key] + values for key, values in data.items() ]                 

print(" | ".join(headers))
for row in data:
    print(" | ".join(row))
```

Result

```
--- after ---

Name | index1 | index2
deviceid | 123 | 245
devicemodel | Windows | Linux
```